# How do I make a Button in VB.NET Allow a User to Select a File?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I am making a Crypter in Visual Basic Express Edition 2010, and I am experiencing some problems. I am trying to make it so the user clicks on a button in the GUI, and it allows them to pick a file to Crypt. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that? Here is the code I originally used to make it, but it is not working :( All help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .FileName = ""
        .Filter = "Executables (*.exe)|*.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .Title = "The Justice Crypter"
        .ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = .FileName
        infectedfile = TextBox1.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: On the GUI, the User clicks on the button that opens the file that they want to be Crypted, but instead of their folder showing up, there is an error for [FileName = ""] and it won't let the user access their files. Please help! :)

Comment: What are you using for your OpenFileDialog WPF doesn't have a native one that I know of?

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With OpenFileDialog1

Comment: NullReferenceException Was Unhandled

Comment: Also.... Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenFileDialog is a WPF wrapper of the Win32 Control this works for me.

```
Class MainWindow 
    Dim WithEvents openFileDialog1 As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Executables (*.exe)|*.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            .Title = "The Justice Crypter"
            .ShowDialog()
            TextBox1.Text = .FileName
            'infectedfile = TextBox1.Text
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am now getting an error at .FileName = "" saying this: Object variable or With block variable not set. Its the same type, a NullReference

Comment: @user1760869 I am not sure what you are doing, where are you declaring your OpenFileDialog it needs to be a Module level object. the above code does work I checked it before posting

Comment: You fixed it, thank you very much Mark. Also, I just want to specify, when you are stating Dim WithEvents openFileDialog1 As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog will my program remain 64 bit?

Comment: @user1760869 That is a very good question, I compiled above as 64 bit and it ran with no errors.

Comment: @user1760869 - Don't forget to mark this as the answer, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenFileDialog1` is null.
You need to initialize it to a `New OpenFileDialog()`.

Comment: Let me specify what is happening. The code I am using is this: